# Is there any way to use URL looking path for use command in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm a bit newbie to PHP syntax and struggled with 'use' command. The name of the folder in my server contains '.' (dot). When I try to use that path, it throws an error. How can I use that path appropriately?

```
use ..\..\api.company.com\App\Application\Actions\API\APIRoot;
```

It throws the following error:

> Syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting T_STRING or T_FUNCTION or T_CONST or T_NS_SEPARATOR

I tried the following, but same problem exists.

```
$dot = '.';
use ..\..\api${dot}company${dot}com\App\Application\Actions\API\APIRoot;
```

and

```
$dot = '.';
use ..\..\api{$dot}company{$dot}com\App\Application\Actions\API\APIRoot;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you confusing `use` with `require` or `include`?  Why would you specify a folder path with `use`?

Comment: There is no specific reason to use `use`. I would try `include` and `require`. I'm gonna try and let you know the result.

Comment: I think he confuse Path with use Namespace.

Comment: I tried `include` and `require`, the syntax error fixed. Thank you very much for pointing to the correct place.